# How to continually change xml element in public LocationCallback function? - Android

Tags: java, android-studio, settext, findviewbyid

I have access on speedView (getText is fine), but setText is not working! There are no errors, but text of speedView does not change.

The activity_ar_navigation uses mapbox vision.

```
 public LocationCallback locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
        super.onLocationResult(locationResult);


        LayoutInflater inflater1 = LayoutInflater.from(LocationService.this);
        View root = inflater1.inflate(R.layout.activity_ar_navigation, null, true);
        TextView speedView = (TextView)root.findViewById(R.id.speed);
        speedView.setText("this is a test");

        (.....)

    }
};
```

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.mapbox.vision.ar.view.gl.VisionArView
    android:id="@+id/mapbox_ar_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/speed"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:text=""/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since you have not supplied this code, I'll ask are you sure the value of `temp` is not null or empty? Have you tried with a `String` literal?

Comment: Yes, it is not null, I have also tried with a String literal. I will edit the post to be clear

Comment: Don't you see the text in the TextView or doesn't the `setText` method affect the View at all? What does `speedView.getText();` return after `speedView.setText("this is a test");`? Add this line to your code `Log.d("Debugging speedView", speedView.getText());` and check the log.

Comment: setText changes the text of the element, I tested it with getText. I can see the change on console (using Log.d) but I cant see the text in the TextView....